# Excel VBA Run-time error 13 - mismatch when box is blank

Tags: vba, excel, isnullorempty

I am stuck in VBA. I have tried other solutions on the website but still can't get it right. I am using multiple modules and forms to get some information input into cells of Excel. But, when the msgBox is left blank it gives me a type 13 mismatch error. I have tried isNull but don't fully understand how to use it.

Any help would be much appreciated, and please keep any answers as simple as possible as I am a novice programmer at best. Thanks

```
Sub GetEndCostGateFees()
    Dim qtyGateFees As Double
    Dim msg As String

Const MinCost As Integer = 0
Const MaxCost As Integer = 200

msg = "Please enter the cost, per tonne, of Gate fees "

Do
    qtyGateFees = InputBox(msg, "Gate Fees")

    If IsNull(qtyGateFees) Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter a value. Enter 0 if none")
        End If

    If IsNumeric(qtyGateFees) Then
        If qtyGateFess >= MinCost And qtyGateFees <= MaxCost Then Exit Do
        End If
        msg = "Please enter a valid number"
        msg = msg & vbNewLine
        msg = msg & "Please enter number between " & MinCost & " and " & MaxCost
        Loop

Sheet25.Range("B43").Value = qtyGateFees
```

End Sub

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the beginning of your modules.  That will make one of the problems here evident.

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the user to enter only Numeric Input then use `Application.InputBox` with `Type:=1`

```
Sub sample()
    Dim Ret As Variant
    Dim msg

    msg = "Please enter the cost, per tonne, of Gate fees "

    Ret = Application.InputBox(msg, "Gatefees", Type:=1)

    If Ret <> False Then
        '
        '~~> Rest of your code here
        '
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change qtyGateFees to Variant:

```
Dim qtyGateFees As Variant
```

I believe you're getting a Type Mismatch error because you're trying to assign a blank value to a variable that is dim'd as "Double".

You could then try this rather than isNull:

```
If qtyGateFees = "" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring your variable as a `Variant`, you could use error handling (which is a good practice anyway).

```
Option Explicit
    Sub GetEndCostGateFees()
        Dim qtyGateFees As Double
        Dim msg As String

        Const MinCost As Integer = 0
        Const MaxCost As Integer = 200

        msg = "Please enter the cost, per tonne, of Gate fees "

        Do
            On Error GoTo TypeM
            qtyGateFees = InputBox(msg, "Gate Fees")
            On Error GoTo 0

            If IsNumeric(qtyGateFees) Then
                If qtyGateFees >= MinCost And qtyGateFees <= MaxCost Then Exit Do
            End If
            msg = "Please enter a valid number"
            msg = msg & vbNewLine
            msg = msg & "Please enter number between " & MinCost & " and " & MaxCost
        Loop

        Sheets(Sheet25).Range("B43").Value = qtyGateFees

    Exit Sub

        TypeM:
        If Err.Number = 13 And Err.Description = "Type mismatch" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a value. Enter 0 if there were no fees."
            Err.Clear
            Resume
        Else
            Debug.Print Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
        End If

    End Sub
```